# Obtaining feature vector from existing matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, n-gram, countvectorizer

If I use Scikit-learn to configure a CountVectorizer object and pass a matrix *M* of *n* sentencens (of varying length) to the fit_transform function, I can for example obtain an n-gram representation *F*. Like this:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 1,
                             max_features = 2000,
                             ngram_range = (2, 2),
                             analyzer="word)

F = vectorizer.fit_transform(A)
```

This works well. *F* will now have the shape (2000, *n*) because I've set max_features to 2000.

But let's say that I obtain one more sentence, and would like to generate a vector that aligns with the features of *F* and has the same length (2000).. is this even possible, or do I need to keep the original matrix *M*, add the new sentence to it, and then re-generate all the features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you can transform additional sentences using `vectorizer.transform(['New sentence here'])`.

Comment: But If I have understood fit_transform correctly, it does two things: First, for all sentences (rows in a matrix) it fits the entire model and learns the complete vocabulary. Second, it transform all rows into feature vectors. So if I would use the vectorizer again, it wouldn't care about what is inside the feature matrix F, right? Or does the CountVectorizer object remember what it has created previosly?

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized you wrote transform, not fit_transform. My bad. So after Reading about transform in the documentation, I do not get any wiser. I will try to find additional information. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the `transform` vs `fit_transform` is important. When you do the initial `fit_transform`, the vectorizer object does exactly what you described, and also saves the trained model and vocabulary. From there, you can transform any new collection of documents simply using the `transform` method. As long as you don't call 'fit_transform` (or `fit`) again, the model will not change. To see this, you could try `F_new = vectorizer.transform(A)`. It should be exactly the same as your first `F` variable.

Comment: this is awesome. Just what I want. Thank you so much, you saved my night!